# 9-patch image not stretching correctly

Tags: android, listview

I am using a 9-patch image for my ListView as the background for each list item. In a previous app, this image worked great as each list item had a set height so I could manually set the dp height of the list item. But for this app the height of each list item is dynamic (using wrap-content) and with this particular 9-patch image the list items look too tall each time, like this:

[image]

The image looks like this:

[image]

Here is my XML layout for each list item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowUp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowup"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreText"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="492"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowdown"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/messageText"
            android:text="Message text message text message text"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/timeText"
            android:text="14 hours ago"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't tink the issue is from the 9 patch (that could, indeed, be optimized). I think you are giving a fixed height to your row items.

Comment: Nothing in my XML indicates that that I can see

Comment: How are you applying this in code? It seems like you're overwriting the padding somewhere. Also, as @BobMalooga said, you could definitely optimize that 9-patch to be much smaller.

Comment: I am applying it using a custom array adapter. It isn't happening in code, as the XML preview itself shows the row to be tall like this.